# Is a maximal planar bipartite graph containing cut vertices isomorphic to a star?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, bipartite-graphs

A simple graph $G$ is called *maximal planar bipartite*  if it has the property: if we add an
edge (without adding vertices) to $G$, we obtain a graph which is no longer planar, bipartite or simple.

See the following article for the above definition.

- [1] G. Ringel,  Two trees in maximal planar bipartite graphs[J]. Journal of Graph Theory, 1993, 17(6): 755-758.

But Ringel  was quick to assert that **a maximal planar bipartite graph divides the plane into quadrangles only**.

When maximal bipartite planar graphs are 2-connected, I see no problem. But if a maximal planar bipartite graph has some cut vertices, it seems incorrect. For example,  for the stars (a star $S_k$ is the complete bipartite graph $K_{1,k} $), clearly they are maximal planar bipartite  graphs. But they are not quadrangulations (a graph can be embedded in a surface such that every face is a quadrangle).

Furthermore, **my question** is whether all maximal planar bipartite graphs **except stars** are quadrangulations.

Some examples show that it seems right.

[image: ![enter image description here]

But how do we prove it rigorously?

PS (screenshot from Literature 1):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are (and well spotted).

Here's an old proof I have typed up. I think you can shorten it substantially however! To do so, I'd directly consider the walk bounding a face. It consists of alternating black / white vertices. Try argue using maximality that the walk is either a 4-cycle, or a star.

**Lemma 1:**
Every face of a 2-connected plane graph is bounded by a cycle.
This is well known (see, for example, Diestel)

**Theorem 1:**
Let $G$ be an mpb graph of minimum degree $\delta$ embedded in the plane. Then every face of $G$ is bounded by a 4-cycle if and only if $\delta \geq 2$.

*Proof:*
Let $G = (V,E)$ be an mpb graph and consider an embedding of $G$ in the plane. If every face of $G$ is bounded by a 4-cycle, then clearly $\delta \geq 2$. Conversely, assume $\delta \geq 2$. As $G$ is bipartite, $V$ can be partitioned into two sets, $B$ and $W$, such that every edge of $G$ is incident with one vertex of $B$ and one vertex of $W$.

First, we show that $G$ is 2-connected: Assume to the contrary, and without loss of generality, that $b_1\in B$ is a cut-vertex. Let $w_1, w_2$ be vertices of different components of $G-b_1$ such that $w_1, b_1, w_2$ are consecutive vertices of the walk bounding some face $f$ of $G$. As $w_1, w_2$ are adjacent to $b_1\in B$, it must be that $w_1, w_2 \in W$. Since the minimum degree of $G$ is at least 2, $w_2$ has a neighbour $b_2\in B$ such that $w_2, b_2$ are consecutive vertices of the walk bounding $f$. Since $b_2$ and $w_1$ are in different parts of the bipartition of $G$, and are both on the boundary of $f$, the maximality of $G$ implies that $w_1b_2 \in E$. Thus, $w_1, w_2$ lie in the same component of $G-b_1$, a contradiction. Hence $G$ is 2-connected.

We now show that every face of $G$ is a 4-cycle: Since $G$ is 2-connected and bipartite, by Lemma 1, every face is bounded by an even cycle. Thus it suffices to prove that every face of $G$ is bounded by a cycle of length less than 6. Assume, to the contrary, that some face $f$ of $G$ is bounded a cycle $C$ of length $k\geq 6$ and, without loss of generality, that $f$ is in the interior of $C$. Let $b_1, w_1, b_2, w_2, b_3, w_3$ be six consecutive vertices of $C$ with $b_1, b_2, b_3 \in B$ and $w_1, w_2, w_3 \in W$. As $b_1$ and $w_2$ lie on the same face and are in different parts of the bipartition of $G$, the maximality of $G$ implies that $b_1w_2 \in E$. Since the interior of $C$ is a face, $b_1w_2$ must lie in the exterior of $C$. Similarly to $b_1w_2$, the maximality of $G$ necessitates that $w_1b_3\in E$. If $w_1b_3$ lies inside $C$, it subdivides $f$, contradicting that $f$ is a face. If $w_1b_3$ lies outside $C$, it crosses $b_1w_2$, contradicting the planarity of $G$.

**Theorem 2:**
If $G$ is an mpb graph of minimum degree one, then $G$ is a star.

*Proof:*
Let $G = (V,E)$ be an mpb graph with partite sets $B$, $W$, and consider an embedding of $G$ in the plane. Without loss of generality, $v\in B$ is the neighbour of a vertex of degree 1. We claim that every neighbour of $v$ has degree 1. Assume to the contrary that $v$ has a neighbour of degree greater than 1. We can find neighbours $u,w$ of $v$ with $\text{deg}(u) = 1$ and $\text{deg}(w) \geq 2$ such that $u,v,w$ lie on the same face, $f$, of $G$. Let $b\in B$ be a neighbour of $w$, other than $v$, which lies on the boundary of $f$. Since $u$ and $b$ lie on the boundary of the same face, in different parts of the bipartition of $G$, they are adjacent by the maximality of $G$, contradicting the fact that the degree of $u$ is 1.

Comment: A nice analysis. The proof is not only intuitive but also rigorous.